# Heroku and rails stuck at pg_try_advisory_lock()

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Picture :

[image: Here's where I'm stuck]

Text :

> vriska@vriska-HP:~/Sites/railsbridge/test_app **$ heroku run rails
>   db:migrate**
>
> Running rails db:migrate on ⬢ shrouded-atoll-19895... up, run.7023
>   (Free)
>
> D, [2018-05-31T15:42:19.154167 #4] DEBUG -- :    (0.8ms)  SELECT
>
> pg_try_advisory_lock(1002123553364509380)
>
> D, [2018-05-31T15:42:19.169018 #4] DEBUG -- :    (1.2ms)  SELECT
>
> "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY
>
> "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
>
> D, [2018-05-31T15:42:19.178631 #4] DEBUG -- :
>   ActiveRecord::InternalMetadata
>
> Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  "ar_internal_metadata".* FROM
>   "ar_internal_metadata"
>
> WHERE "ar_internal_metadata"."key" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["key",
>   "environment"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
>
> D, [2018-05-31T15:42:19.186823 #4] DEBUG -- :    (0.7ms)  BEGIN
>
> D, [2018-05-31T15:42:19.188802 #4] DEBUG -- :    (0.7ms)  COMMIT
>
> D, [2018-05-31T15:42:19.189731 #4] DEBUG -- :    (0.7ms)  SELECT
>
> **pg_advisory_unlock(1002123553364509380)**

And it's stuck here, forever. I'm expecting a response like this :

> Migrating to CreateDrinks (20160706063236)
>
> ==  20160706063236 CreateDrinks: migrating  ...

ps : I'm following this exactly

http://installfest.railsbridge.org/installfest/

Ruby 2.3 rails version 5.2

Comment: Going to need some more information. Your rails version, Your migration code. That would be a start

Comment: @CarlMarkham 2.3 is my version, I don't know what a migration code is :\

E: rails version - 5.2.0

Comment: @CarlMarkham : I'm having the same problem. Migration code is several files. Seems like a lot to paste in a stackoverflow question. The real question is - what is this "pg_advisory_unlock" thing, and why is it being called?